# The cheapest way from Krabi town to Krabi airport

Tags: budget, airport-transfer, thailand, kbv, krabi

I am in krabi Thailand now and tomorrow is my flight  at 2100 to Jakarta.  I am only 1 person and always travel like a backpacker. I would like to ask 1 question here:

What is the most cheapest way to reach krabi airport from krabi town in Thailand ?

I am not interested in taxi and shuttle buses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I am at Krabi airport. I went to River View hotel and there were song thews waiting. I just asked how much to airport and he asked 50 THB and waiting time 15 mins.

While I was waiting on the road there were a few motorcyclists waving their hands. When I approached them they started asking where I wanted to go. I said Krabi airport and I have 50 THB. He smiled and took me to airport.

Apparently he dropped me in front of the airport entrance. So there is basically another option available for solo travellers, which is a motorcycle.

Comment: I used to do this all the time in Vietnam, but it's developing fast and I didn't do it once on my last visit. You probably could've haggled too!

Comment: Actually it was really amazing because there was a big line of cars going towards airport, the motorcyclist took literally 20 minutes. Had I used other options, it wouldn't had been that fast. I paid him 70 in the end

Answer (score 4):

You don't have too many choices.

The Airport Bus is around 90 baht from Krabi town, but you need to get yourself from where you are staying to it's nearest pick up point (ask your front desk.

Song theaws will get you close to the airport for around 50 to 100 baht, but they can not enter the airport so will drop you at the highway and you walk in.

Taxis and hotel shuttles are in the several hundred baht range, which I suppose you have already discovered.

Comment: @Hippietrail - Song theaws are not tuk tuks, they are covered pick up trucks with two long benches in the back. (song - two, theaw - bench)

Comment: I got some information from my hostel that song theaw runs in front of river view hotel prices from 50 to 100 thb

Comment: @Tom: Songthaews are not pickup trucks. Pickup trucks are รถกระบะ (rot graba). Some songthaews are modified pickups, some are modified trucks. The key functional difference important to a traveller is that a songthaew is a share taxi and a tuk-tuk is a private taxi. A new arrival doesn't always know the difference between songthaew, tuk-tuk, samlor, and jumbo.

Comment: @hippietrail - Song theaw as encountered by the vast majority of travelers is a pick up truck with covered back and two benchesh, some areas do use larger truck based song theaw. Tuk tuk are three wheeled vehicles, motorcycle powered with a covered area for driver and a couple of passengers.  Song theaw can be shared or private depending on what you ask of the driver, tuk tuk are usually private.  But my comment came out because you edited my answer to state that song theaw are a type of shared tuk tuk which is totally incorrect.

Comment: Maybe farang now care a lot more about the number of wheels and lexical ontologies when looking for transport from the airport. Great language lesson though. Forget to mention skylabs though or that not all tuk-tuks carry passengers. Maybe in some other thread (-:

Answer (score 4):

It's December 2017. Songtaews seem to ask from 300 to 400 baht per one way to the airport. We tried to lower the price and after some walk and many refuses we lowered to 250 baht (2 people). No way to get a tuktuk or a shared songtaew, at least not later than 18h. The motorbikes offered to take us for 150 bath per person, which was the worst possible option. Shuttle bus is still 90 baht/person. I don't know where did you take the info for 2016, if prices are rising so fast in a few years Thailand will be as expensive as Europe...

Answer (score 3):

You can walk out to the main road and wave down a songthaew or motorbike. The songthaews on the main road only charge me 20 baht that day. To get to airport take motorbike if you don't have big luggage. The songthaew stop to go to the airport is in front of river hotel near the river. I was told my local people 30 baht.  I'm taking it tomorrow. I can't upload the pictures of the songthaew station.  Yeah but it located at [The River View hotel](http://www.riverviewhotel-krabi.com) for location how to get there